# Can I create dummy variables if my variables are ordinal categories?

Tags: r

Can I create dummy variables if my variables are ordinal categories?
this makes sense?

Furthermore, I want to study the correlation of the categorical variables, do I do it before or after transforming them to dummies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can turn ordinal variables into dummy categories. Sometimes this is right, sometimes it is not. But it's a common thing to do.

If your variable is ordinal, then you can use a Spearman's correlation on the ranks. However, you changed words in the middle of your question from "ordinal" to "categorical". Just in case: You can't do Spearman on nominal values.

You *could* do correlations on the dummy variables, but that would ignore the ordinal nature of the data.

If this is the start of a more complex analysis, such as regression, then ordinal variables can be quite tricky to deal with, but one method that seems good to me but is not much used is optimal scaling.

Comment: Thank you very much, one more question: for my nominal categorical variables I am using the VIF method to study multicollinearity and correlations. Should I apply this method before transforming the variables to dummies?

Comment: Yes.  But I like condition indexes better than VIF.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much!